# Vector element assignement C++

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management

I have this C++ function

```
void fun_example(vector<double> *matrix, int var, vector<int> *vec){
    for (int i=0; i<var; i++){
        vec[i] = i%var;
        vec[i] = matrix[i%tot_size];
    }
    vec[0] = 0;
}
```

But it gives error when using:

```
vec[0] = 0 or vec[i] = i%var,
```

while it's ok when writing:

```
vec[i] = matrix[i%tot_size].
```

It says:

```
no operator "=" matches these operandsC/C++(349)
NRG.cpp(109, 16): operand types are: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>> = int
NRG.cpp(109, 16): function "std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(std::initializer_list<std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type> __l) [with _Tp=int, _Alloc=std::allocator<int>]" does not match because argument #1 does not match parameter
NRG.cpp(109, 16): function "std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> &&__x) [with _Tp=int, _Alloc=std::allocator<int>]" does not match because argument #1 does not match parameter
NRG.cpp(109, 16): function "std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> &__x) [with _Tp=int, _Alloc=std::allocator<int>]" does not match because argument #1 does not match parameter
```

No push back, no emplace back. I want to use simple assignement, I already reserved space before calling the arrays in the function.

Comment: `vec`  is a pointer, so you need `(*vec)[i]`. But your design looks fishy anyway, so please [edit] and show a [mcve]. Espcially the code that calls `fun_example` would be helpful.

Comment: You probably want `void fun_example(vector<double> & matrix, int var, vector<int> & vec)` instead of `void fun_example(vector<double>* matrix, int var, vector<int>* vec)`.

Comment: thanks @jabberwocky. That's what i wanted to write.